# Flyback converter design using UC3843

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, flyback, ripple

I am designing a offline power supply which will 24 V as output with 2.5 A. I found UC3843 as better option. I used TI we bench tool to design my power supply. This is the schematic I got from it. The given transformer design, I given to one manufacturer and I got a transformer. I rigged up the circuit as it mentioned. But in this I am getting three issues:

1. Audible whining noise across the transformer. Transformer and snubber resistors are getting hot.
2. Sometimes (randomly) restarts while I am connecting 1 A load.
3. Small ripples present in output when there is no load.

How to resolve those issues.

[Schematic](https://1drv.ms/b/s!Al-d__TJfdKJlRl_51mYlnC8hkIu?e=JJHilr)
[Transformer Specification](https://1drv.ms/b/s!Al-d__TJfdKJlRe9dTVLCBJVR1FW?e=316m3b)

Comment: Hello Balaji, e2e.ti.com would also help in resolving this.

Comment: 1) and 2) are common "features"

Comment: hi andy aka what does mean by common features?

Comment: As for 1, it could be a design issue as in a saturating transformer or something more simple as "coil whine". Have you tried to pot your transformer or soak it in varnish to prevent windings from moving? 2. OCP? 3. Please show an oscillogram.

Comment: The circuit layout can be critical with switching circuits. Component selection is also critical. As Andy suggests, the transformer whining is not unusual but sometimes can suggest something is not correct. The snubber by design dissipates energy and will get hot. Component choice is key to ensure the temperature rise is within acceptable limits.

Comment: I don't understand why TI keeps promoting slope compensation by buffering the oscillator sawtooth, this is a nonsense considering the noise in these circuits. Also, with a TL431 in the secondary side, the internal op-amp must be disabled by grounding the FB pin and hooking the COMP pin to the VREF pin via a 10k resistor. Then the opto collector goes straight to the COMP pin. If time permits, I will try to document an answer tonight.

Answer (score 5):

I looked at the circuit proposed by TI around the UC3843 and it is truly a [Rube Goldberg Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine), especially for the feedback arrangement. Below are the points to look at and correct for a reliable operation:

1. when the regulation "intelligence" lies in the secondary side as in your circuit, disable the internal op-amp. The part has been designed for this purpose considering the 1-mA maximum sourcing capability of the COMP pin. So ground the FB pin and load the COMP pin by a 10k resistance (or a bit higher for a better standby power) connected to the 5-V reference voltage. For stability and noise purposes, add a 1-nF capacitor between the COMP pin and the IC GND. This cap. is really close to the controller while the two copper traces from the opto are routed separately: the emitter goes to the IC GND (and *not* to any ground, go to the IC ground pin) while the collector goes to the COMP pin:

[image]

2. you need slope compensation for this design but stay away from the original recommendations of Unitrode, duplicated here by TI: do *not* touch the oscillator by trying to buffer the ramp. These are low-current paths that can easily be polluted if the layout is bad. The best is to remove that circuitry and use the DRV signal to build a ramp as proposed by Ridley in the 90's. The DRV pin is low impedance in essence and you build a robust ramp generator without bothering the oscillator. This is what I've seen in the industry for years. The calculation details are given slide 80 in my [APEC 2018](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202018.pdf) seminar:

[image]

3. the TL431 in a type 2 configuration is fairly simple, no need to add extra components around. See my presentation from [2009](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/The%20TL431%20in%20Switching%20Power%20Supplies.pdf): a single capacitor between the cathode and the reference pin then another cap. (the 1-nF) between COMP and ground will create a pole-zero pair which, associated with a pole at the origin (an integrator) gives the transfer function of a type 2 compensator.

Finally, I would arrange your circuit as below (keep the RCD clamp that I omitted for simulation speed):

[image]

The steady-state operating point confirms the 24-V regulation at a 2.5-A output current and the open-loop gain gives a 1-kHz crossover with a good phase margin. This can be further optimized but it will do well for tonight:

[image]

Finally, a transient step from 1 A to 2.5 A confirms the good transient response of this converter:

[image]

A few comments for the end:

- keep connections very short, especially those carrying high currents like the output rectifier, the RCD clamp, the MOSFET with \$R_{sense}\$ etc.
- lay all the small-current components as close as possible to the UC384x. For instance, the sense resistance which is of small value can be "far" from the IC but resistance \$R_2\$ and capacitor \$C_3\$ must be close to the IC pins. That is important if you don't want to pick noise.
- same for the timing or slope compensation components, close to the IC
- you *should* characterize the optocoupler ac response and CTR distribution if this adapter is meant for production. For a hobby application, the recommendations I gave should do.
- finally, I determined the compensation for a 120-V dc output but if the ripple on the input is too deep, meaning the bulk capacitor is too small, then the valley voltage might operate the converter at a value way lower than 120 V. See the design example slide 122 of the seminar I gave as a reference.
- and, last but not least, you can simulate this isolated converter using one of my free [ready-made templates](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) operating on the free SIMPLIS demo version Element.

Good luck with this project!

**Additional Edits**

When debugging a switching converter, it is good to add protection features like an over-voltage protection (OVP) circuitry. The below example shows a simple one which has proven to be quite efficient in many situations. A cheaper version exists (without opto) and consists of observing the auxiliary winding but the below one will do well:

[image]

A soft-start is also an important feature to limit the power-on stress and the overshoot on the secondary side. A well-known solution built around a capacitor and a couple of diodes is given also.

Please note - and this is something not shown in the simulation circuit - that both primary- and secondary-side grounds must be physically separated for galvanic isolation. I know it's obvious but it's not reflected on the schematic for ease of implementation and it is important to underline this point.

Comment: Thank you Tim for correcting the misspelling of the name. Its equivalent in the UK is [Heath Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Heath_Robinson) ^_^

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to provide me with these steps to solve my problem. Your guidance is truly invaluable, and I really appreciate your help. I'll make sure to follow the steps carefully and let you know how it goes. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello, no problem, happy if this is useful. You can validate the answer when it works on your side : ) I will add a soft-start to the circuit diagram and possibly an OVP, as this last one is always useful when debugging. Please note that it is recommended to go through a PCB design or a compact [veroboard ](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veroboard) with short connections. As usual, be very careful with high voltage and use an isolation transformer or a HV isolated dc supply for the first attempts.

Comment: And one small doubt in schematic, what is R8 and R31, if it is diode can you please give specification. And voltage rating of c8

Comment: Ah yes, these are piece-wise linear (PWL) components for SIMPLIS. They are diodes here. So "\$R_8\$ is a 1N4148 for instance and ignore \$R_{31}\$ as it is there to replace the body diode of the MOSFET. So just keep the small 47-pF/1 kV capacitor across drain and source \$C_8\$.

Comment: Again thank you for this answer.

Comment: Do we need to use Both OVP and TL431 regulator circuit in secondary side? or OVP circuit is enough to get proper output voltage.

Comment: No problem, typoes happen. :) @BalajiN: the OVP circuit can be used alone, the downside is poorer regulation, and, compensation is more difficult to do. (For circuits like this, it usually gives a first order sort of transfer function, but beware controls with large phase shift; it would not do well on a voltage-mode converter!)

Comment: The OVP circuit is a redundant system, silent in normal operation when the TL431 regulates and active if the main loop is broken. As highlighted by *Tim Williams*, using this circuit alone is not recommended unless a poorly-regulated output is acceptable with this current-mode converter. I like to have an active OVP for the first power-on sequence in case the main loop is badly adjusted or defective.